# Gazebo9 hangs on "Preparing Your World..." on macOS Mojave 10.14.1

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I seemed to have solved the GUI scaling issue by installing the latest version of qt (5.12.0) but now Gazebo hangs at preparing your world (for hours).  It doesn't seem to be downloading any models, /usr/local/share/gazebo-8/models only contains ground_plane and sun.  I've tried manually copying all the model folders there but it doesn't help.

This is on both Gazebo8 and Gazebo9

```
~ gazebo --verbose
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 8.6.0
Copyright (C) 2012 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

[Msg] Waiting for master.
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 8.6.0
Copyright (C) 2012 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

[Msg] Waiting for master.
[Msg] Connected to gazebo master @ http://XXX.X.X.X:XXXX
[Msg] Connected to gazebo master @ http://XXX.X.X.X:XXXX
[Msg] Publicized address: XX.XX.XX.XX
[Msg] Publicized address: XX.XX.XX.XX
[Wrn] [GuiIface.cc:117] Failed to get QCocoaScreen for NSObject(0x0)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/21285/gazebo9-hangs-on-%22preparing-your-world...%22-on-macos-mojave-10.14.1/) by [variable](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/7373/variable/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2018-12-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Danylo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/7478/danylo/) on 2018-12-11**:
For me the workaround has been so far to switch between Qt 5.12.0 for RViz and 5.11.2 for Gazebo where the UI is overscaled but kind of usable anyway.

**Comment by [variable](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/7373/variable/) on 2018-12-12**:
I see others are aware of it and working on it here: https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues/2531/gazebo-gui-rendering-is-scaled

**Comment by [snogar](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/7572/snogar/) on 2018-12-14**:
FYI, I am getting the same problem.

**Comment by [variable](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/7373/variable/) on 2018-12-14**:
Did you see my answer that minimizing the window fixes it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Minimizing the window and opening it back up fixes the issue.  Sounds like there's a bug fix already submitted.

---

Originally posted by [variable](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/7373/variable/) with karma: 13 on 2018-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0